# Windows Phone AutoCompleteBox was not found

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

My XAML file errors when I try `<toolkit:AutoCompleteBox>` although I added a reference to the Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.dll file. Everywhere I have read says this should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 steps to make this work:

1. First reference the assembly in your project
2. Secondly reference the namespace in your xaml file
3. Finally point to the control you want to use in the namespace

I guess that you're missing the second step:

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
```

Comment: I agree... he didn't create an xml namespace mapping for the CLR namespace.